# Laravel session value is not showing in app/Hlepers/common_helpers.php and the base controller

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.3

I am a beginner in laravel and developing an application in `Laravel 5.3`. I created one `common_helper.php` file in `app/Helpers` directory and created a `service provider` and added it in `config/app.php`.

I tried to call a function located in the `common helper` from my controller. It is going to the helper file. But **Not showing the session value in the common helper, which is available in the controller.**

**I already did something in laravel 5.2. But there the same structure working perfectly**

What may be the issue? I couldn't figure out it. Please help

**common_helper.php**

```
<?php


use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Menu_master;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image as Image;

function check_session()
{
    echo Session::get('email');die;
    if (Session::has('email') && Session::has('login') && Session::has('role_id') && Session::has('role_name'))
    {
        if (empty(Session::get('email')) || Session::get('login') !== 'true' || empty(Session::get('role_id')) || empty(Session::get('role_name')))
        {
            Session::flush();
            Redirect::to('/')->send();
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Session::flush();
        Redirect::to('/')->send();
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

**I am calling the `check_session()` from the controller `construct` function like below**

```
public function __construct(){
    check_session();
}
```

Comment: question did you successfully set your session?

Comment: @NewbeeDev, Yeah and I am getting it with in the controller methods. Bu not in the constructor in the main controller function

Comment: can I see how you push your session

Comment: did you try to print out your Session array?

Comment: Yeah. It is printing with in the inner methods. But not in the constructor.

Comment: can you include the code which set your session

Answer (score 0):

You should use the session's namespace first.

```
use Session;
//or
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

Comment: I used the same. Still the session not available in the construct. I think it is something related to L5.3. They are not supporting the session in construct. The same code in L5.2 is working

Comment: I create a new laravel5.3 project and test this. session is accessible in constructor. `public function __construct () { dd(Session::get('email')); }` gives me the correct answer. new another project and test it?

Comment: how about updating your laravel?

Comment: @forehalo, Thank you for the try. Can you please provide the full controller code?